# Log in details for every site

Tags: discussion, login, auto-login

Is there a possibility that I log in once and can access all the set of sites which are under Stack Exchange as each and every time its annoying for me to log in into the website and work on the same. This is kind of security and limitation but its time consuming too.

Comment: We have this, if you are logged in on any site, and have an account on a site that you're visiting, you'll be automatically logged into that site too. What browser are you using and are third party cookies enabled? Do you have any ad-blocking extensions installed? They can interfere with central authentication. In short, this should be working for you.

Comment: Additionally, when you use exclamation points (!!!) - we understand you to be screaming at us in anger - If that's _not_ what you wanted to convey, try to avoid them :)

Comment: Thank you for the tip Tim, I will avoid these exclamations :) When I m little surprised I use those in my questions so will take care of that from next time.

Answer (score 3):

It already exists. If you're already logged into the StackExchange network, you'll get the below message whenever you open a site where *you've already have an account*. It auto-logins you and just asks you to refresh the page.

[image: Auto-login Message]

If you do not have an account on that site already, then you'll be asked to login into that site. But even there, all you need to do is specify the ID to be used to login and if that is how you've logged into the SE network, it'll create an account for you in that site and log you on without asking for the credentials again.

As [Tim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218124/log-in-details-for-every-site/218125#comment707220_218124) mentioned, if this feature is not working for you, then it might be because of cookies being disabled on your machine, or probably some ad-blocker plug-in interfering with central authentication, etc. Otherwise, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work for you.

Comment: @AlienArrays - That's the magic of free-hand. It is the *All-in-one* writing style ;)

Comment: Might be of interest to some having problems: JavaScript must be enabled for the site you want auto login to work **and** `stackexchange.com` + `stackauth.com`. Furthermore, if you're blocking [HTTP referers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), `stackauth.com` needs that, too. And clear your cookies before you give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you are visiting a stack-exchange site for the first time, even though you are already logged into any other site say stackoverflow, you would not get the auto-login request.

**Why?**

Simply because for the system, you are just a guest user at the instant. You would need to register using the current session before you can actually get the auto-login to work.

For the sites which you have registered once, the auto-login should work and if it doesnt work, then maybe an issue with cookies or similar as @R.J mentioned in his answer.

If you are requesting for a feature request then you would need to tag clearly. Hope this makes sense.